# QtCreator issues tab is empty

Tags: xcode, cmake, qt-creator

I'm experiencing an issue with QTCreator. It doesn't parse compiler output and IssueTab is always empty, in spite of compiler output contains some. It seams that complier output is totally made to stdout and not to stderr (compile output is totally grey). 
That happens if I use XCode Cmake generator. When I switch to Unix MakeFiles generator issues are shown normally, but I stacked to Xcode as project is really old and is written to support only XCode.
Search in google for some specific flags for Xcode generator hand't provided any useful response.
Thus I'm asking the Community.

Answer (score 0):

A small hack: `1>&2`. Now everything goes to stderr, and QtCreator tries to parse it

[image]

**UPD:** `-quiet` makes output more clean

[How to make xcodebuild print compile errors and warnings to stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63688882/how-to-make-xcodebuild-print-compile-errors-and-warnings-to-stderr)