# How to make xcodebuild print compile errors and warnings to stderr?

Tags: xcode, compilation, qt-creator, xcodebuild

Seems like xcodebuild prints everything to stdout.

```
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project test.xcodeproj build -target test -configuration Debug -jobs 3 2>err
 # xcodebuild stdout with bunch of warnings and errors

$ cat err
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC _build/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test.o /Users/me/test/test.cpp normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

That doesn't let my IDE(QtCreator) correctly parse the output.

And clang, actually, prints errors and warnings to stderr. But xcodebuild redirects everything to strdout for some reason. Is there a way to make xcodebuild print errors and warnings to stderr except `1>&2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try running the command with -quiet option as follows.

```
# Do not print any output except for warnings and errors
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project -quiet
```

So you can just pipe warnings and errors by using -quiet option and to filter only error you can use **2> ./errors.log**

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project -quiet test.xcodeproj build -target test -configuration Debug -jobs 3 2> ./errors.log
```

There are other tools to check such as **xcpretty** and **xcbeautify**.

https://github.com/xcpretty/xcpretty (I prefer this)

Comment: Thanks! `-quiet 1>&2` does the thing. Do you happen to know if xcpretty or xcbeautify can redirect warnings and errors to stderr without altering them?

Comment: Your welcome. I am happy to solve your problem. Well Before Apple has introduced the -quiet flag, I was using xcpretty to reduce build logs and to turn the output from mass to this neatly formatted output.  So it will just format and make it human-readable. What's more, it is still a handy tool to use nowadays such as xcodebuild | xcpretty -c